# GROMACS: Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: c++, linux, coredump

I have an error: Illegal instruction (core dumped). What should I do?

I meet this error when using GROMACS, a package for my research. I don't think this is a GROMACS's error but an error of C because GROMACS is written from C++ (I know this after have been googling around). That's why I put this question in here. I know nothing about C. Is it impossible to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [my conversation to GROMACS team](http://gromacs.5086.x6.nabble.com/How-to-provide-the-FFTW3-install-directory-td5015481.html). In short:

- Install `fftw3 by ./configure --enable-float`, `make`, `make install`
- Install gromacs by `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local`, `make` and `make install`
- If it says that GROMACS isn't installed, then use `source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC` (you may need to add this line into your `~/.bashrc` file so that it will auto activate anytime you open a new shell)

If you use an old machine, I think you should use old version. Hope this help :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you compile `GROMACS` yourself ? And most importantly, are you executing the software on the same machine on which it was compiled ?

I was running into the same issue after compiling `GROMACS` on a computer (login node of a cluster) and trying to use the executable on another computer (compute node of the cluster) with an inferior set of instructions.

If so, have a look at [this page of the GROMACS manual (this depends on the version you are trying to compile)](http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Installation_Instructions_5.0?highlight=root#simd-support) to determine the highest common instruction set of your different machines and recompile gromacs with the appropriate value for `-DGMX_SIMD`. In my case, it looked like:

`cmake .. -DGMX_SIMD=SSE4.1`

Answer (score 0):

Compile GROMACS for the machine you will run it on. Most easily done by doing so on the machine where you will run it.